# Is there a way to retrieve the cell address of a comment in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a short macro to manipulate some comments in Excel. It would be useful to have a way to find out the cell address/location of a comment in my active worksheet - is there any way to do this with the comment object in Excel? Or failing that, any clever workaround that would give me the same result?

Some illustrative pseudo-code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
dim wb as Workbook
dim ws as worksheet
dim cmt as Comment

set wb = ActiveWorkbook

for each ws in wb.sheets
    for each cmt in ws.comments
        debug.print cmt.address ' Pseudo code
    next cmt
next ws
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cmt As Comment

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    For Each cmt In ws.Comments
        'Debug.Print cmt.Address ' Pseudo code
        Debug.Print cmt.Parent.Address
    Next cmt
Next ws
```

For info: .parent returns the parent object of the comment object, which in this case would be the cell.

Comment: And of course `cmt.Parent.Row` and `cmt.Parent.Column` give you the individual row and column numbers (e.g. 6 for column F)